# Gulp usemin exclude files

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-usemin

Let's have index.html

```
<!-- build:js js/lib.js -->
<script src="../lib/angular-min.js"></script>
<script src="../lib/angular-animate-min.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->

<!-- build:js1 js/app.js -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/thing-controller.js"></script>
<script src="js/models/thing-model.js"></script>
<script src="js/views/thing-view.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

On the output we will have 2 files in `js` directory: `lib.js` and `app.js`

For `usemin` code from this files I'm using this task:

```
return gulp.src(config.src.html.index)
    .pipe(usemin({
        css: [rev],
        html: [function () {
            return minifyHtml({empty: true});
        }],
        js: [ngAnnotate, uglify, rev],
        inlinejs: [uglify],
        inlinecss: [minifyCss, 'concat']
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.build.root));
```

This task also runs ngAnnotate, uglify tasks for `lib.js` it takes a long time to make all this thigs working. I need to runn only these tasks for all files which will be in `app.js` file.

How to exclude library files from this addtional tasks ?

Comment: You can use this :     gulp.src(['js/**/*.js', '!js/**/*.min.js']) to exclude file

Comment: This will affect other tasks, I need to exclude only for ngAnnotate or uglify